# Information of the user in comments

Tags: 7, theming, comments

I want to show the information of the author in his comment. By default it shows the name and the picture, I want to add:

- The number of node and created comments
- The number of obtained [userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints).

What code should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @arpitr wrote in his answer, you should edit the `comment.tpl.php` file in your theme. Use [`userpoints_get_current_points()`](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/userpoints-7.x-1.x!userpoints.module/function/userpoints_get_current_points/7-1) to display the user's points. You can easily count the number of nodes and comments with a database query:

```
$uid = $comment->uid;
$nodes = db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node WHERE uid=$uid AND status=1")->fetchField();
$comments= db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment WHERE uid=$uid AND status=1")->fetchField();
```

Put these lines in comment.tpl.php too and print them where you want the values to appear.

Comment: I know it can be tough for beginners, but at least you have to try to find an answer on the internet first, because this is just php coding. In this case use `$uid = $comment->uid;`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Beleive me, I looked a lot a lot on the Internet.. But indeed there it was not too much complicated ;)

Answer (score 1):

Each comment runs through comment.tpl.php template, where the php variables are replaced with actual values and from where you get the actual html

Before going to tpl files, execution passes through template_preproces functions, preprocess function allows you to add new variables or override existing variables which you use on tpl files.

Now in your case it is comment.tpl.php, if you see the file in bartik theme the code

```
  <div class="attribution">

    <?php print $picture; ?>

    <div class="submitted">
      <p class="commenter-name">
        <?php print $author; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="comment-time">
        <?php print $created; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="comment-permalink">
        <?php print $permalink; ?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

is responsible to show comment author information. In order to override the html you can simply copy the comment.tpl.php from parent theme to your base theme and start overriding the html. If you want to introduce new variable to the template, then use template_preprocess_comment(), for example on your theme template.php

```
function your_theme_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  // To Debug what is inside variables already
  dpm($variables);
  // To override exisiting variable
  $variables['author'] = 'my test author';
  // To add any new variable to comment.tpl.php
  $variables['author_comment_count'] = _some_function_fetch_comments_count($user_id);
  $variables['author_nodes_count'] = _some_function_fetch_node_count($user_id);
  $variables['author_user_points'] = _some_function_fetch_user_points($user_id);
}
```

Now you will have three more variables to use on comment.tpl.php as
`$author_comment_count`, `$author_node_count`, `$author_user_points`

Use them on template, example

```
<div class="attribution">

    <?php print $picture; ?>

    <div class="submitted">
      <p class="commenter-name">
        <?php print $author; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="comment-time">
        <?php print $created; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="comment-permalink">
        <?php print $permalink; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="comment-count">
        <?php print $author_comment_count; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="node_count">
        <?php print $author_node_count; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="user-points">
        <?php print $author_user_points; ?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks arpitr for your detailed answer. I understood for the modification of the theme, but not to obtain the number of created comments / nodes and the number of points. These variables are not proposed by Drupal? I tried with your example, but I have errors like "Undefined variable"

Comment: no, the count you have to get by your own the reason I added placeholder functions as _some_function_fetch_comments_count  and so. So try putting some hard coded value and clear your drupal caches to see you have overridden the comment template appropriately, later you can add define those functions and replace with hard coded values

Comment: But I don't know how to obtain these variables... I looked a lot, found modules but nothing really works...

Comment: You do not need modules for these three functions, write custom query to get data , check the module api from user point it must have a function already.

Comment: for comment i try in template : `code function MYTHEME_get_user_comments_count($uid) {
    $query = db_select('comment', 'c');
    $query->condition('uid',$uid,'=');
    $query->addExpression('COUNT(cid)', 'comments_count');
    $result = $query->execute();

    if ($record = $result->fetchAssoc())
        return $record['comments_count'];
    
    return 0;
} ` and in comment/tpl : `code <?php print MYTHEME_get_user_comments_count(['comments_count'], $comment->uid); ?> ` but don't work :(

Comment: its a separate problem in itself, please add it as separate question if it is not already asked by someone.

Comment: It was a part of my initial question, but ok. I asked the question [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/174159/count-number-of-nodes-and-comments). Thank you for your help