# How to show the number of nodes and comments?

Tags: 7, database, comments, theming

I want to show the number of nodes and comments of the author in the author's comment.

I try to put in template :

`function MYTHEME_get_user_comments_count($uid) { 
   $query = db_select('comment', 'c'); 
   $query->condition('uid',$uid,'='); 
   $query->addExpression('COUNT(cid)', 'comments_count'); 
   $result = $query->execute(); 
   if ($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) return $record['comments_count'];
   return 0; 
}`

And in comment.tpl :

`<?php print MYTHEME_get_user_comments_count(['comments_count'], $comment->uid); ?>`

But it doesn't work.

Where have I forgery? Is this the right way?

Comment: I've just answered your previous question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/174113/information-of-the-user-in-comments/174160#174160 and provided the code you're looking for. I'd therefore close this question.